# Ubuntu Apache2 Basic Authentication Issue

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, configuration, webserver

I have an issue with an internal networking utility server that I am building, specifically around Basic Authentication.

Now I have managed to get it to work with the following configuration:-

```
root@P-UIDMON-02:/# /usr/local/scripts/LinuxVersion.sh

### Linux Standard Base Information
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.04
Release:        23.04
Codename:       lunar
### Kernel Release
6.2.0-1015-azure
### Version of Apache2
Server version: Apache/2.4.55 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2023-10-26T13:37:01

root@P-UIDMON-02:/# /usr/local/scripts/ApacheConfig.sh
### /etc/apache2/apache2.conf Config File
ServerName p-uidmon-02.acas.example.org
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
### p-uidmon-02.conf Site Specific Config File
<Directory /var/www>
    SSLRequireSSL
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    Redirect "/" "https://p-uidmon-02.acas.example.org/"
    ServerName acas.example.org
    ServerAlias p-uidmon-02.acas.example.org
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        AllowOverride All
        SSLRequireSSL
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/auth/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    <FilesMatch "\.(?:cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    ServerName acas.example.org
    ServerAlias p-uidmon-02.acas.example.org
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key
</VirtualHost>
### /var/www/html/.htaccess File
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/auth/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

My problem (that I don't understand) is that I want to be able to use the Basic Authentication details against the Virtual Host and NOT have to put a `.htaccess` file in the specific directory, but the only way I can get this to work is by having the `.htaccess` file in the directory.  It is like it is ignoring the Virtual Host `<Directory>XYZ</Directory>` statements.  If I remove the `.htaccess` file, it doesn't challenge me; if I have it in there, then I get the challenge!

Although it's working, it is driving me insane trying to understand why it doesn't work if I take the `.htaccess` away.

Can anyone of you explain to me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you've got three major issues:

1. You have put the `htaccess` configuration statements in the Virtual Host managing port 80 rather than the one managing port 443
2. You have put your SSL configuration statements into the non-SSL port 80 host instead of the SSL port 443 host
3. The Virtual Host on port 80 quite reasonably does an immediate redirect to the Virtual Host on port 443 so any configuration statements there will be (mostly) ignored

Comment: Wow, thanks Chris.  I move all the statements from port 80 to 443 and then deleted the .htaccess file in the /var/www/html directory and this is now challenging me for an authentication as expected.  Many thanks for your help on the matter.  I was getting so confused and frustrated with myself as i knew that i was close to the answer, but clearly not there.